# AsyncTask with Accelerometer - duplicate entries

Tags: java, android-asynctask, accelerometer, wear-os

I am attempting to log accelerometer results from Android Wear to a file using an `AsyncTask`. However, readings seem to be duplicated in my instance of `AsyncTask` - `AccelerometerEventLoggerTask` and I have no clue why.

I have a `WearableService.java` class defined as follows which extends a `Service` and implements an abstract `SensorEventListener`:

```
public class WearableService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        //get accelerometer
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        // register listener
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            new AccelerometerEventLoggerTask().executeOnExecutor(SERIAL_EXECUTOR, event);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

From that, this creates an `AsyncTask` designed to write to a file (for now, this executes a simple log):

```
private class AccelerometerEventLoggerTask extends AsyncTask<SensorEvent, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(SensorEvent... events) {
        SensorEvent event = events[0];

        Log.d(TAG, "" + event.values[0] + "; " + event.values[1] + "; " + event.values[2]);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting duplicate entries when the programme is running normally (this is not the case with a breakpoint). This is an example log:

[image: duplicates]

Why is this? Interestingly, when I run the same `Log.d` line in `onSensorChanged`, no duplicates. So something strange is happening in the `AsyncTask` implementation `AccelerometerEventLoggerTask`.

If somebody can shed some light on the issue, or know why - I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730628/onsensorchanged-in-android-continuously-getting-triggered-in-emulator/43457789#43457789

Comment: Thanks! This could be useful. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onSensorChanged in android continuously getting triggered in emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730628/onsensorchanged-in-android-continuously-getting-triggered-in-emulator)